# Are there DSLRs that embed image stabilisation info in EXIF data?

Tags: dslr, metadata, image-stabilization

Are there DSLR:s (or any other camera for that matter) that embed image stabilisation info in EXIF data? I can't recall I've ever seen that. If not — why not? It seems like a useful marker.

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? Was it on/off? How much stabilization was used? And what kinds of things would you want to use this information for; we may be able to help you reach the same goal with different information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you're looking for, yes, at least some cameras do. From my Pentax K-5ii:

```
exiftool mksm0001.jpg|grep SR

SR Result                       : Stabilized
SR Half Press Time              : 4.25 s or longer
SR Focal Length                 : 40 mm
```

Pentax calls its in-body image stabilization system "Shake Reduction" — *SR*.

These are from the [Pentax Makernotes](http://gvsoft.homedns.org/exif/makernote-pentax-3-tag0x005c.html) section, not part of the general standard, so results will vary from maker to maker, but the basic answer to your question is *yes, there are DSLRs that embed this info in EXIF*.

Comment: Just to add to this: My Canon 550D with a Sigma 18-50mm lens does not store it in the RAW file. I couldn't find any information regarding that using exiftool. Here the stabilization is done in the lens though.

Comment: @BartArondson Yeah, I suspect that it's more common in cameras with in-body stabilization, but I haven't actually researched.

Comment: The Canon R with the RF 70-200, shows image stabilization as `Image Stabilization`.